# T4MVC with ActionNames

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I just included T4MVC in my project and ran into an issue. I'm passing data to my javascript via hidden text fields and I need to be able to pass the names of controllers and their actions. Here's what I have:

```
<input type="hidden" id="logErrorUrl" name="logErrorUrl" value="@Url.Action("LogJavaScriptError", "Error") />
```

I'd like to be able to do:

```
<input type="hidden" id="logErrorUrl" name="logErrorUrl" value="@Url.Action(MVC.Error.LogJavaScriptError("")) />
```

For some reason this isn't working. I was thinking because LogJavascriptError doesn't return an ActionResult. FYI LogJavaScriptError also takes in a string but I really just want the name of the action. I also tried @MVC.Error.ActionNames.LogJavaScriptError but it doesn't show up perhaps again because it doesn't return an ActionResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T4MVC only works with action methods that return an ActionResult. If your method doesn't need to return anything, then the recommended thing to do is to return an EmptyResult, e.g.

```
    public virtual ActionResult SomeAction() {
        // Do stuff

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```